# Vector spaces isomorphic, then dual spaces isomorphic

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, analysis, functional-analysis, banach-spaces

If we know that there is a (topological) isomorphism between two Banach spaces $X,Y$ called $\phi \in L(X,Y)$. Then the appropriate isomorphism between the dual spaces $X',Y'$ is given by $\phi' \in L(Y',X')$.

I was wondering: What is the fastest way to see that this $ \phi'$ is actually an isomorphism? Does anybody here have a good idea to show this fast? I mean sure, you could show that it is onto and injective, but this does not seem to be a fast idea.

Comment: Plus one. Any reason for not adding the banach-spaces tag?

Comment: Maybe the word "fast" needs a definition?

Comment: @MattN. my list of tags was exhausted ;-)

Comment: @Tomás most fast is defined as the infimum over all possible number of symbols to prove this. does this serve to you as a definition? ;-)

Comment: Alright : ) If you replace calculus with banach-spaces it might get you much better help because different people will look at your question. Just a thought.

Comment: The proof given in this answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/131353/5798) seems fairly short.

Comment: This is just by functoriality.

Comment: @Herbert Maybe you could post an explanation of the connection with functorality, for the benefit of readers who are not familiar with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can easily construct an inverse to $\phi^*$, it is given by $(\phi^*)^{-1}=(\phi^{-1})^*$, indeed we have:
$$\left<(\phi^{-1})^*\phi^*v,x\right>=\left<\phi^*v,\phi^{-1}(x)\right>=\left<v,\phi\phi^{-1}(x)\right>=\left<v,x\right>$$
for all $x\in X$ and $v\in X^*$. Thus $(\phi^{-1})^*\phi^*=1$, and similarly $\phi^*(\phi^{-1})^*=1$.

Comment: what is $\langle,\rangle$?

Comment: Daniel, there is no inner product, the spaces in the question are Banach spaces. For a proof see e.g. the link I give in the comments to the question.

Comment: @MattN. It is not an inner product, it is just the natural pairing between $X$ and $X^*$, i.e. $\left<v,x\right>=v(x)$ for $v\in X^*$ and $x\in X$.

Comment: Ok, good. I take back my comment! : )